# Editing other processes memory

Tags: c++, memory, process, edit

I've been playing around with editing memory of simple programs I have created using the Windows function WriteProcessMemory. It was working well, however I noticed that I could not edit certain parts of the programs memory, where all the ASCII which is meant to be output is stored.

I cannot seem to write to addresses 0x00442000 onwards in my program, unless I use another program such as OllyDbg. What is the reason for this and is there a way I can get around it?

Answer (score 2):

Because they are read-only memory, I expect. You'll need to use VirtualProtect to remap it as writeable.